# Пропадает контент в слайдер свайпер при пролистывании тачскрином

Tags: css

Не нашел в нете ответа подскажите кто сталкивался. В слайдер свайпер при пролистывании тачскрином влево у первого слайда пропадает контент. Т.Е. когда слайд становится активным (выезжает справа на лево) то контента нет. А при малейшем сдвиге опять появляется. При пролистывание вправо все норм.

Answer (score 0):

Сменил позиционирование контента с абсолютного на статическое баг исчез. Может пригодится кому.